# Not reading the second data from json

Tags: json, protractor

I am trying to read data from json (2 cycles) and add an entry. the first time, the data added successfully but during the second cycle, it failed. below are the details.  Also working when run with page object and without reading from json;

The "test_pom_fromjson" added successfully but when running for the test_pom_fromjson_first it failed with error saying no element found using `element(by.id('s2id_autogen10')).click();` which is the locator for location column.

Refer the screenshot and html code for the page - https://pastebin.com/ZXyRx1tv
[image: add page]

```html
mo.ts: pageobject for the below spec file

    var mo = function () {
this.createbutton = function () {
        var createb = element(by.css('button[title="Add Master Obligation"]'))
        //var createbutton = element(by.buttonText('↵ ↵ Add Master Obligatio...↵ '))
        browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();arguments[1].click();", createb, createb);


    }


    this.MasterObligationName = function (value) {


        element(by.model('obligation.ObligationName')).sendKeys(value);
    }

    this.Module = function (value) {


        element(by.id('s2id_TaxProcess')).click();
        element.all(by.repeater('item in obligation.TaxProcess.list')).get(value).click();
    }

    this.Location = function (value) {


        element(by.id('s2id_autogen10')).click();
        element.all(by.repeater('item in obligation.Jurisdiction.list')).get(value).click();
    }

    this.CentralObligation = function (value) {


        element.all(by.model('obligation.CentralObligation')).get(value).click();
    }
    this.Type = function (value) {


        element(by.id('s2id_txtReturnType')).click();
        element.all(by.repeater('item in obligation.ReturnType.list')).get(value).click();
    }
    this.Years = function (value) {


        element(by.id('s2id_txtTaxYear')).click();
        element.all(by.repeater('item in obligation.TaxYears.list')).get(value).click();
    }
    this.Periods = function (value) {


        element(by.id('s2id_txtPeriod')).click();
        element.all(by.repeater('tem in obligation.Periods.list')).get(value).click();
    }
    this.Forms = function (value) {


        element.all(by.id('s2id_txtForms')).get(0).click();
        element.all(by.repeater('item in obligation.Forms.list')).get(value).click();
    }
    this.Reports = function (value) {


        element.all(by.id('s2id_txtForms')).get(1).click();
        element.all(by.repeater('item in obligation.Reports.list')).get(value).click();
    }

    this.savebutton = function () {


        var saveb = element(by.css('button[title="Save"]'))
        browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();arguments[1].click();", saveb, saveb);


    }

    module.exports = new mo();
```

```
   

spec.ts:                                                                         var mo = require("../page/mo.ts")
    var testData = require('../testdata/testdata.json');

    testData.forEach(function (data) {
        it('create and save master obligation', function () {
            browser.sleep(10000);
            mo.createbutton();
            browser.sleep(10000);
            mo.MasterObligationName(data.Master_Obligation_Name)
            mo.Module(data.Module);
           mo.Location(data.Location);
            mo.CentralObligation(data.Central_Obligation);
            mo.Type(data.Type);
            mo.Years(data.Years);
            mo.Periods(data.Periods);
            mo.Forms(data.Forms);
            mo.Reports(data.Reports);
            mo.savebutton();
        })

    })  




testdata.json:
[{
    "Master_Obligation_Name": "test_pom_fromjson",
    "Module": "2",
    "Location": "1",
    "Central_Obligation": "0",
    "Type": "2",
    "Years": "1",
    "Periods": "1",
    "Forms": "1",
    "Reports": "0"
}, 
{
    "Master_Obligation_Name": "test_pom_fromjson_first",
    "Module": "2",
    "Location": "1",
    "Central_Obligation": "0",
    "Type": "2",
    "Years": "1",
    "Periods": "1",
    "Forms": "1",
    "Reports": "0"
}]
```

Comment: I just want to know, Where it failed? For the second time to add master obligation, does the  page appear and error came or the master obligation  page was missing?

Comment: hey @KishanPatel good morning. thanks for taking your valuable time to look into the issue.                                                                                     It failed with error saying no element found using element(by.id('s2id_autogen10')).click(); which is the locator for location column. so i am not sure how it found for the first time and failing in the second or third

Comment: 2 options you can try:
1.Wait for some time before that click
2. Either id number is auto generated so it might be changed everytime, so use some other locator.

Comment: i have added time and not working;yes you should be right...the id should be auto generated.... i will try to identify with different locator then..will let you know..

Comment: There is no problem in your json. After adding 1st data from json, did it click add new master obligation?

Comment: yes it did clicked on the add new button, enter the second obligation name and selected the module. the problem started with selecting the location and definitely it should be with id issue as you told...i will change the locator and see. will let you know

Comment: the problem might be here as well. `element.all(by.repeater('item in obligation.Jurisdiction.list')).get(value).click();`

Comment: this is not the right way to select the value?should i go by xpath?

Comment: Your type of field is location ?Is it a text field? I need to see the html dom for location

Comment: location is a bootstrap down and it has search field also. i have put the html snippet here - https://pastebin.com/KQa1xRPL

Comment: In location put some wait
`element(by.id('s2id_txtReturnType')).click();
Browser.sleep(2000);
        element.all(by.repeater('item in obligation.ReturnType.list')).get(value).click();`

Comment: kishan, your guess is right. the problem is beacuse of the locator since the id will be auto generated..you are brilliant... i have updated code as below and all the entries from json got added.                        element.all(by.id('s2id_Jurisdiction')).get(1).click();       
element.all(by.repeater('item in obligation.Jurisdiction.list')).get(value).click();

Comment: so one quick question, you suggest to go by xpath always? or which is the best way for the element locator?

Comment: Go for `ng` tags first if the `value-attribute` pair is easy to locate. 
I follow this:
`ng` - `id` - `class` -  `xpath` - `css`

Comment: ok right thanks kishan...i will follow this.

Comment: Okay. I hope your queries are resolved now.

Comment: yes ! add it as an answer so that i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options you can try:

1.Wait for some time before that click

2.Either id number is auto generated so it might be changed everytime, so use some other locator.

If the id is auto-generated then look for some other locator then:

```
element.all(by.id('s2id_Jurisdiction')).get(1).click(); 
element.all(by.repeater('item in obligation.Jurisdiction.list')).get(value).click();
```

> OR you can also try the following way:

```
var module = element(by.xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 's2id_autogen')]")).get(1).click();

var location= element(by.xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 's2id_autogen')]")).get(2).click();

var type = element(by.xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 's2id_autogen')]")).get(3).click();
```